# how filter() a db-backed tibble using a variable?

Tags: r, dbplyr

I am attempting to filter a database-backed tibble by piping to a `filter()` command and am observing unexpected behavior:

If I filter using `filter(pos == variable)`, I get the same result regardless of what value I assign to the variable. However, filtering with the value, e.g. `filter(pos == 12345)` works - the result changes as it should for each different value I'm filtering on.

Is this an aspect of lazy evaluation or tidyeval? What is the correct way to `filter()` a DB-backed tibble using a variable?

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), path = ":dbname:")

ex_data <- tibble(
  pos = c(10510138, 10510507),
  ref = c("CATA", "TCA"),
  alt = c("C", "T")
)

copy_to(con, ex_data, "variants", temporary = FALSE)

toQueryDB <- tbl(con, "variants")

pos = 10510138
(result <- toQueryDB %>% filter(pos == pos)  %>% select(pos, ref, alt) %>% head(1))
# 10510138 CATA  C 

pos = 10510507
(result <- toQueryDB %>% filter(pos == pos)  %>% select(pos, ref, alt) %>% head(1))
# STILL 10510138 CATA  C !!!

(result <- toQueryDB %>% filter(pos == 10510138)  %>% select(pos, ref, alt) %>% head(1))
# 10510138 CATA  C

(result <- toQueryDB %>% filter(pos == 10510507)  %>% select(pos, ref, alt) %>% head(1))
# 10510507 TCA   T 

DBI::dbDisconnect(con)
```

And my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.7.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.18     rstudioapi_0.7   bindr_0.1.1      magrittr_1.5     tidyselect_0.2.4 bit_1.1-14       R6_2.2.2        
 [8] rlang_0.2.2      fansi_0.3.0      blob_1.1.1       tools_3.5.1      utf8_1.1.4       cli_1.0.1        DBI_1.0.0       
[15] dbplyr_1.2.2     yaml_2.2.0       bit64_0.9-7      assertthat_0.2.0 digest_0.6.17    tibble_1.4.2     crayon_1.3.4    
[22] bindrcpp_0.2.2   purrr_0.2.5      memoise_1.1.0    glue_1.3.0       RSQLite_2.1.1    compiler_3.5.1   pillar_1.3.0    
[29] pkgconfig_2.0.2
```

Comment: Tidy eval strikes again! Thanks, @MrFlick - if you provide it as an answer instead of a comment, I'll mark it as correct and upvote it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have

```
filter(pos == pos)
```

dplyr doesn't try to figure out which `pos` is which and it assumes they both are coming from the data that's piped into the function. If you want to inject the value of a variable from outside the data being passed in, then you need to use the bang-bang rlang operator (`!!`). You should use

```
filter(pos == !!pos)
```

Comment: It seems to behave if I use better variable naming, too, e.g. `filter(pos == var)`

Comment: You really still should use `!!` in that case as well. That makes it much clearer where values are supposed to be coming from.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on MrFlick's answer, you can also use `!!` followed by parentheses for an in-place calculation instead of just evaluating an object, such as:

```r
con %>%
  tbl("some_table") %>%
  filter(date > !!(Sys.Date() - 1000))
```

Longer, reproducible answer:

```r
library(dplyr)
# we'll use duckdb here, of course
library(duckdb)

# connect, will be in-memory
db <- dbConnect(duckdb())

# create data set with 10k dates between 25k days ago and today
df <- data.frame(date = Sys.Date() + runif(10000, min = -25000, max = 0),
                 value = runif(10000))

# write to the duckdb
dbWriteTable(db, "test", df)

# I want all values from last 1000 days, though this won't work:
db %>%
  tbl("test") %>%
  filter(date > Sys.Date() - 1000)
#> Error in `collect()`:
#> ! Failed to collect lazy table.
#> ! rapi_prepare: Failed to prepare query SELECT *
#> FROM test
#> WHERE (date > (Sys.Date() - 1000.0))
#> LIMIT 11
#> Error: Catalog Error: Scalar Function with name date does not exist!
#> Did you mean "main.day"?
#> LINE 3: WHERE (date > (Sys.Date() - 1000.0))
#>                        ^

# now let the magic start, use !! with parentheses:
db %>%
  tbl("test") %>%
  filter(date > !!(Sys.Date() - 1000))
#> # Source:   SQL [?? x 2]
#> # Database: DuckDB 0.8.1 [root@Darwin 22.6.0:R 4.3.1/:memory:]
#>    date        value
#>    <date>      <dbl>
#>  1 2022-05-28 0.809 
#>  2 2021-10-11 0.267 
#>  3 2023-01-09 0.657 
#>  4 2021-12-05 0.0280
#>  5 2020-11-10 0.0411
#>  6 2021-12-11 0.0912
#>  7 2021-04-05 0.726 
#>  8 2021-02-10 0.315 
#>  9 2020-12-18 0.877 
#> 10 2022-11-01 0.230 
#> # ℹ more rows
#> # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Tada!